# mpdf setAutoTopMargin doesn't work for first page

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

We are creating invoice with dynamic header in mpdf using setAutoTopMargin = 'stretch' to avoid header and content overlap. Problem is it overlaps content with header only on first page but works fine for rest of the pages.

Example code for header part.

```
<htmlpageheader name="myheader">
<table width="100%"><tr>
<td width="50%" style="color:#0000BB; "><span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 14pt;">Acme Trading Co.</span><br />123 Anystreet<br />Your City<br />GD12 4LP<br /><span style="font-family:dejavusanscondensed;">&#9742;</span> 01777 123 567</td>
<td width="50%" style="text-align: right;">Invoice No.<br /><span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 12pt;">0012345</span></td>
</tr></table>
</htmlpageheader>

$mpdf->setAutoTopMargin = 'stretch';
```

As you know there are 2 ways to add header in mpdf and this issue arises only when we use htmlpageheader tag in html.
If we use `$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($header);` to set header via php code, it works fine on all pages including first page. but it's not possible for us to use this due to some constraint.

We have already checked this but it isnot working for us.
[mPDF setAutoMargin not working for first page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32142922/mpdf-setautomargin-not-working-for-first-page)

Is this known issue of mpdf?  Please help me on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same error, then i fixed just now.

I got an error because I have more **div** tags on content page.

I set the page in two php files : header & footer.
then set with

```
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($header);
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer)
```

One file **php** for setup **mpdf**.

I set

```
$mpdf->setAutoTopMargin = 'stretch';
$mpdf->setAutoBottomMargin = 'stretch';
```

Sorry maybe too late to answer.